# Is it possible to use a string with multiple words as json key?

Tags: javascript, json

it's common to have json keys without spaces. 
I can access a value of a json simply calling it's key. But if my json looks like

```
{
     "kemon acho": "I am fine"
}
```

How can I print `I am fine` ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just do:

```js
var j = { "kemon acho": "I am fine" };
console.log(j["kemon acho"]);
```

Comment: Great. I tried to print using the plain texts and gave me error now using variable like 'j' works perfectly. 
Another thing, how can I print the key itself and not the value?

Comment: You get all the keys of the object by: var keys = Object.keys(j);
keys is an array here

Answer (score 3):

Simply use squared brackets notation:

```
myJSON["kemon acho"]
```

**[Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)<sup>*MDN*</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property value, but if you have control over your JSON, use camel case or underscore case. They're more robust.

```js
var j = {
   "kemon acho": "I am fine"
}

console.log( j["kemon acho"] );
```

A better JSON structure would be camel case:

```
var j = {
   "kemonAcho": "I am fine"
}
```

or underscore case:

```
var j = {
   "kemon_acho": "I am fine"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets like this:

```
data = {
     "kemon acho": "I am fine"
}

cosole.log(data["kemon acho"])
```